# How can I detemine the joint p.d.f. of $(X,Y)$, i.e., $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider $Z=X+Y$, where $X,Y$ and $Z$ are random variables with p.d.f.s denoting $f_X(x)$,  $f_Y(y)$ and $f_Z(z)$, respectively. Then, how can I detemine the joint p.d.f. of $(X,Y)$, i.e., $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$?

In addition, is there possible to calculate $f_{X,Z}(x,z)$ and $f_{Y,Z}(y,z)$?

Appreciate!

Comment: Convolution is one way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, even if random variables $X$ and $Y$ have pdf $f_{X}$
and $f_{Y}$, it may happen that the random vector $(X,Y)$ does not
have pdf $f_{XY}$.

Let us clarify some terminoloies: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be
a probability space. Given a random variable $X$, its distribution
$\mu_{X}$ is a Borel measure $\mu_{X}:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow[0,1]$
defined by $\mu_{X}(B)=P\left(X^{-1}(B)\right),$ $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
If there exists a Borel function $f_{X}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
such that $\int_{B}f_{X}(x)dx=\mu_{X}(B)$ for any $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$,
we say that $X$ has a pdf. Since $\mu_{X}\geq0$, we have that $f_{X}\geq0$
($m$-a.e., where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$).
Moreover, $f_{X}$ is not unique but is only unique $m$-a.e. Moreover,
$X$ has pdf if and only if $\mu_{X}$ is absolutely continuous with
respect to the Lebesgue measure $m$ (in the sense: $m(B)=0\Rightarrow\mu_{X}(B)=0$).

This setting can be extened to multi-dimensional case. For example,
the (joint) distribution $\mu_{XY}$ of the random vector $(X,Y)$
is a Borel measure $\mu_{XY}:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{2})\rightarrow[0,1]$
such that $\mu_{XY}(B)=P\left((X,Y)^{-1}(B)\right)$. Here $(X,Y)$
is regarded as a map: $(X,Y):\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$, $\omega\mapsto(X(\omega),Y(\omega))$.
Similarly, if there exists a Borel function $f_{XY}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
such that $\mu_{XY}(B)=\int_{B}f(x,y)\,dm_{2}(x,y)$, where $m_{2}$
is the Legesbue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then we say that $(X,Y)$
has a (joint) pdf. Again, $(X,Y)$ has a pdf if and only if $\mu_{XY}$
is absolutely continuous with respect to $m_{2}$. In this case, the
pdf $f_{XY}$ is unique up to $m_{2}$-a.e. and $f_{XY}\geq0$ $m_{2}$-a.e.

Counter-example that $X,$ $Y$ both have pdf but $(X,Y)$ does not
have pdf: Choose a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ such
that there exists a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
with $X\sim N(0,1)$. Define $Y=X$. Clearly, $X$, $Y$ both have
pdf, denoted by $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ (in fact, $f_{X}=f_{Y}$). We
prove that $(X,Y)$ does not have a pdf. Let $L=\{(t,t)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.
Note that $L$ is a Borel set and $(X,Y)^{-1}(L)=\Omega$, so $\mu_{XY}(L)=P(\Omega)=1$.
On the other hand, $m_{2}(L)=0$. Hence $\mu_{XY}$ is not absolutely
continuous with respect to $m_{2}$ and hence $(X,Y)$ does not have
a pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to find $f_{XY}(x,y)$. Your question phrases it like we have a particular senario, when $X, Y$ are independent. If this is the case, then:

$$f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

So to find the joint distribution we simply multiply the marginal distributions.

Secondly, you ask how to find $f_{XZ}(x,z)$. In this case, we have X, Z, which are not independent (since $Z = X + Y$). Then we find it like so:
\begin{align} 
f_{XZ}(x,z) &= Pr(X=x \ \ and \ \ Z=z)     \\
            &= Pr(X=x \ \ and \ \ X+Y=z)   \\
            &= Pr(X=x \ \ and \ \ Y=z-x)   \\
            &= f_{XY}(x,z-x)               \\
            &= f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)              \\
\end{align}
With the last step following from independence. Of course this is not very general, and only works in this case (since $Z=X+Y$). So when our relationship is different, as long we know the conditional distribution, then we can use Bayes Theorem, extended to PDFs.

$$f_{XZ}(x,z) = f_{Z|X}(z|x)f_X(x)$$

Of course, we must know this conditional distribution.

Although even more generally, if we were to **only** know two dependent marginal distributions, and allow **any** general relationship. There will often be infinitely many joint distributions, so it will become a lot complex. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_distribution_for_conditionally_dependent_variables).

Comment: Then how to do $f_{Z|X}(z|x)$?

Comment: For discrete case, does pdf exist?

Comment: Sorry @Dave, I see what your question is really asking. So in general, if we know X, Y dependent variables, there are infinitely many options for $f_{XY}(x,y)$. So we cannot simply calculate it. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77334/how-does-one-generally-find-a-joint-distribution-function-or-density-from-marg).

Comment: And only if we know the joint distribution explicity does the above work. If we did want to find it, such as in your case, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_distribution_for_conditionally_dependent_variables) gives an answer, but this is honestly beyond my knowledge, so I can't help any further. Sorry for an annoying answer, though I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Actually, I reconsidered it, and amended my answer, which I think should clear things up! Hope that is better.